# On mobile, how do I keep the button the right side of the screen

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile-browser

On my navbar, I have a logo on the left side of the screen and a button on the right side of the screen. On desktop it looks great, but on mobile, the button moves down a bit and next to the logo. How do I keep the button on the same horizontal level at the logo and on the right side of the screen on mobile.

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/eRhpUjRg1E

Here's my HTML:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container topnav">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/logo_company.png">
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="https://www.apple.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-button-outline btn-small">Sign in</button></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.btn-button-outline, .btn-button-outline:link, .btn-button-outline:visited {
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 8px;
color: #355A78;
border: 2px solid #355A78;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
box-shadow: none;

}
.btn-button-outline:active, .btn-button-outline:hover {
    background-color: #355A78;
    color: #fff
}

.btn-button-outline.btn-lg {
    border: 3px solid #355A78;
}
.btn-button-outline.btn-sm {
    border: 1px solid #355A78;
}  
.btn-button-outline.btn-xs {
    border: 1px solid #355A78;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a float:right in your button css.
updated your bootply.
Bootstrap padding was causing it, adjust the padding accordingly. I did as to drop them flush to the bottom.

.navbar-brand {padding: 18px 15px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px;}

Answer (score 0):

You can Add Extra bootstrap default class:"pull-right" in button tag.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-button-outline btn-small pull-right">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: It did put it to the right, but the logo is still moving down 3 pixels so the logo is 3 pixels up on the page. How do I align these on mobile?

Comment: Move the button before the logo.

Comment: or can you please assign css to 
`.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li > a{float:right;}`